# Does Console.Writeline run asyncronously

Tags: stopwatch

I'm testing the speed it takes to convert binary to string to see if it will be a bottle neck. The issue is, the console window is taking longer to complete than the timer suggests...

Simply, the application takes about 10 seconds to run (the GUI is being updated for about 4 -5 seconds, and the update occurs inside the timer start and timer stop calls) but it always shows it only takes around 1 second.

This is the full code to replicate

```
class Program
{
    static List<int[]> binary = new List<int[]>();
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            Add();    //creates the list to convert. I don't need to time this as it's only populating the list
        }
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        foreach (var item in binary)
        {
            var h = item;
            int result = 0;
            int bitValue = 1;

            for (int i = h.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                result += h[i] * bitValue;
                bitValue *= 2;
            }

            Console.WriteLine((char)result);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Done in " + new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks).TotalSeconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Add()
    {
        binary.Add(new int[] { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 });
        binary.Add(new int[] { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 });
        binary.Add(new int[] { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
        binary.Add(new int[] { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 });
        binary.Add(new int[] { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 });
    }
```

Why does the timer show 1 second when I can count how long it takes the GUI to finish updating (4- 5 seconds)? The Console.WriteLine is inside the timer and I don't believe it's sending to the screen in an asynchronous manner but it appears to be behaving in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Because you start the stopwatch after running the Add() operation 5000 times... and this will take time to do.

Comment: I realise that.... but you said "Simply, the application takes about 4 - 5 seconds to run but it always shows it only takes around 1 second"

Comment: My point being that the 5000x Add is part of the overall application time. Why not put another stopwatch around Add - so you know what much of the overall application time is spend on that part. If it's 4 seconds..... then thats why the bit your timing is 1 second.

Comment: Chris, I'm sorry, my question was poorly worded. The application runs for about 8 seconds, 4-5 seconds of that is the GUI updating. I updated my post, apologies

Comment: No worries... I just ran your code and amended the output to show Console.WriteLine($"{result} {new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks).TotalSeconds}"); as it goes.... this does seem to imply the Console.Write line is getting buffered and delayed in being written to the screen. IE the application gets to Console.ReadLine way before the output displays that.

Comment: Infact..... if while it's running you hit a key (after say 4 seconds....) that key press will close the Console window once all the output has finished making it to the screen.